Pandas `merge_asof` but filling with nan values instead of repeating values
I currently have this quick example to work with:
import pandas as pd

left = pd.DataFrame({"left_val": [1, 2, 3, 6, 7]}, index=pd.to_datetime([1, 2, 3, 6, 7], unit='s'))
right = pd.DataFrame({"right_val": ["a", "b", "c"]}, index=pd.to_datetime([1, 5, 10], unit='s'))

# Filter to contain samples that are within the time interval of left
right_filtered = right[(right.index >= left.index.min()) & (right.index <= left.index.max())]

output = pd.merge_asof(left, right_filtered, left_index=True, right_index=True, direction="nearest")

The output I have is:
                     left_val right_val
1970-01-01 00:00:01         1         a
1970-01-01 00:00:02         2         a
1970-01-01 00:00:03         3         a
1970-01-01 00:00:06         6         b
1970-01-01 00:00:07         7         b

But I would like to have the following:
                     left_val right_val
1970-01-01 00:00:01         1         a
1970-01-01 00:00:02         2         Nan
1970-01-01 00:00:03         3         Nan
1970-01-01 00:00:06         6         b
1970-01-01 00:00:07         7         Nan

Main difference is that I want the right values to appear only once in the output dataframe and fill with Nan the other values so that I can create an sparse dataframe and save some space. I would like to avoid iterating the result to set repeated values to Nan because of:

Speed reasons
If I have two consecutive values within right, this method will remove original information

I have been searching for input arguments and methods to do something like this but I could not find it.
Thanks!

To fully grasp the desired logic, could you please provide a more complex example? Maybe with duplicated matches on both sides to see how this should be handled?

As requested, could you update your example to illustrate what should happen with duplicated values? And non-hashable items

I'm not sure it's the desired logic, but if you expect a one-to-one match between the left and right part, shouldn't you perform a merge_asof with right on the left side, then merge back to left?:
out = (left.reset_index()
           .merge(pd.merge_asof(right_filtered, left, direction="nearest",
                                left_index=True, right_index=True
                               ),
                  on='left_val', how='left')
           .set_index('index').rename_axis(left.index.name)
      )

Or if you can have multiple matches, adding a drop_duplicates step:
out = (left.reset_index()
           .merge(pd.merge_asof(right_filtered, left, direction="nearest",
                                left_index=True, right_index=True
                               ).drop_duplicates('left_val'),
                  on='left_val', how='left')
           .set_index('index').rename_axis(left.index.name)
      )

Output:
                     left_val right_val
1970-01-01 00:00:01         1         a
1970-01-01 00:00:02         2       NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:03         3       NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:06         6         b
1970-01-01 00:00:07         7       NaN


This one helped me a lot to reach my answer! There are a few issues (that I did not specify on my post). And these are: 1) left_val must be hashable and 2) left_val cannot have repeated values or otherwise it will mess up the merging

Indeed, the values must be hashable. They should also be unique if you want to maintain the shape. You can drop_duplicates or aggregate in this case.

You can adjust the output after doing .merge_asof:
groups = (output["right_val"] != output["right_val"].shift(1)).cumsum()
output["right_val"] = np.where(~groups.duplicated(), output["right_val"], np.nan)

print(output)

Prints:
                     left_val right_val
1970-01-01 00:00:01         1         a
1970-01-01 00:00:02         2       NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:03         3       NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:06         6         b
1970-01-01 00:00:07         7       NaN


I reached out this solution based on the answers given. The difference is that this one is also compatible with left_val values not being hashable and it also deals with repeated values on left_val
# Having defined right_df and left_df:

# Setup
original_index_name = left_df.index.name
right_df_filtered = right_df[
    (right_df.index >= left_df.index.min()) & (right_df.index <= left_df.index.max())
]
left_df["_range"] = range(len(left_df))

# Merging
asof = pd.merge_asof(left=right_df_filtered, right=left_df, left_index=True, right_index=True, direction="nearest")
left_df = left_df\
    .reset_index(names=["_index"])\
    .merge(right=asof, how="left", on="_range", suffixes=[None, "_delete"])\
    .drop("_range", axis="columns")\
    .set_index("_index")\
left_df.index = left_df.index.rename(original_index_name)
output_df = left_df.loc[:, ~left_df.columns.str.endswith("_delete")]

